# Library trim music file in android studio?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm newbie, i met a problem that how to (or any libray) trim music file in android studio. I searched but not found anything.Thanks.
Example :I have a piece of music from 00:00 to 00:50 seconds long and I want to cut this piece of music from 00:30 to 00:50, what should I do?

Comment: I have a piece of music from 00:00 to 00:50 seconds long and I want to cut this piece of music from 00:30 to 00:50, what should I do?

Comment: yeah! Do you know any library for android can do that ?